# Is there a lower threshold on activity?

Tags: discussion

I've not been around for a while, but activity seems very low. Is there a point at which Stackexchange will archive the site, making it read only or are our hosts content to let us sit here and tick over?

Comment: I can't answer this fully since I don't work for SE, but according to our stats we are still getting quite a few questions and visits every day. The site is no where near the bad performance of some of the other SEs... one example I can think of is french: http://french.stackexchange.com/ and you can see how we compare to other SEs: http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: When sites are closed they don't usually stick around, though a dump of the site data is provided.  That said I think we're doing pretty well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/578/you-need-the-bourgeois-blues and http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/819/is-this-site-active-sorry-for-asking and one I saw the other day about why no-one upvotes that I can't find. Basically: people are interested in Android (hence high hit rate, quite a lot of questions), but this site seems to have a serious problem giving people (including SE people) a reason to stay and interact with the site...

Comment: I think the problem might be that the pool of question askers doesnt overlap very much with the pool of answerers. When the site first opened I had some questions answered, but I've seen very few since that I could answer (to the point where I stopped looking). I'm using SO for work now so will be around more. It's nice to know the site will probably stick around for the time being at least.

Comment: If anyone wants to reopen and post their comment above as an answer so I can accept & close, that would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Making comment an answer)

I can't answer this fully since I don't work for SE, but according to our stats we are still getting quite a few questions and visits every day. The site is no where near the bad performance of some of the other SEs... one example I can think of is french: https://french.stackexchange.com/ and you can see how we compare to other SEs: http://stackexchange.com/sites#

We get a lot of hits from searches and people wanting to ask questions.... if we have any problems, it's with having people around to answer all of these questions (some which are difficult, rare, or specific problems).